# Detect DHCP Request

Tags: python, dhcp

I'm working on a python script right now needs to execute when I receive a DHCP request. I'm running udchpd on my computer and broadcasting a wireless network.

I have no idea really how to go about this. Open a socket connection and listen? Maybe scapy? I don't know.

EDIT: Sorry, I meant DHCP DISCOVER packet, I'm trying to sniff.

Comment: Do you control the DHCP server? i.e. you could make your server execute your script on receiving a discovery packet

Comment: Yes it is a dhcp server running on my desktop. I'm thinking the best thing to do would be to listen on port 67 for an incoming connection. But I feel like theres a better way than to maintain a listen state. Or maybe just program a DHCP server, but I'd rather not

Answer (score 0):

These guys seem to do exactly what you are asking for by using scapy and python. Check their examples [here](http://dodd.io/blog/detecting-rogue-dhcp-servers)

Comment: "Server not found" - thats the reasson why the [answer] page says "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."